# Javascript linked list implementation and pointers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, linked-list, reference

I have implemented a linked list in 2 ways in Javascript, but when doing so, I got really confused about what is really happening.

I was trying to create a mental image about what is being created, and what is pointing to what memory address (based on what I have learned about passing by reference), but I can't do it.

- Are both implementations correct?
- They seem to be doing the same thing, but do they behave in different ways under the hood?
- In option 1, for the prepend() method, I am creating a new object in memory, where "next" property is pointing to the existing memory address of "head" property, but "head" property is now pointing to the new object. Maybe it's a stupid question, but isn't this going in circles? Why does this work?

The differences are between the **append()** and **prepend()** methods.

**Option 1:**

```
class myLinkedList {
    constructor(value) {
    this.head = {
      value: value,
      next: null
    }
    this.tail = this.head;
  }
  
  append(element){
    this.tail.next = {
      value: element,
      next: null
    }
    this.tail = this.tail.next;
  }

  prepend(element) {
    const newObj = {
      value: element,
      next: this.head
    }
    this.head = newObj;
  }
}


const linkedList = new myLinkedList(1);
linkedList.append(2);
linkedList.prepend(0);
```

**Option 2:**

```
class myLinkedList {
    constructor(value) {
    this.head = {
      value: value,
      next: null
    }
    this.tail = this.head;
  }
  
  append(element){
    const newNode = {
      value: element,
      next: null
    }
    this.tail.next = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
  }

  prepend(element) {
    const newNode = {
      value: element,
      next: null
    }
    newNode.next = this.head;
    this.head = newNode;
  }
}

const linkedList = new myLinkedList(1);
linkedList.append(2);
linkedList.prepend(0);
```

Comment: There's no difference. Assigning the new node directly to `this.tail` is no different from creating a temporary variable and then assigning that to `this.tail`.

Comment: BTW, your design doesn't allow for empty lists.

Comment: I guess my problem, simplified down is, why does the below work, why does this not become an infinite circular reference?

`let head = {
  value: 2,
  next: null
}

let newObj = {
  value: 1,
  next: head
}

head = newObj;
console.log(head);`

Comment: You have asked several questions, which makes it too broad. Focus on one question only.  I confirm that both implementations do  the same thing (although they both create a node they shouldn't create -- but that's a different story).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clarified your question in the comments.

The answer has to do with variable binding vs values.

JavaScript has internal representations for values like strings, numbers, user defined objects, and so on.  That representation is the same whether or not the value is named `foo`, or is buried deep in some data structure.

Programs have variables.  At any moment in time, a given variable is bound to a given value.  This gives programmers a way to tell JavaScript what should happen to the values that they are bound to.

Assignment is binding values to things.  When we assign to a variable, it is no longer bound to whatever old value it has been bound to.  That old value may still exist in some data structure, or may become garbage to be cleaned up.  But it is no longer associated with that variable.

And so here is what the sample code that you gave actually does.

```
-- Create a value and bind it to head.
let head = {
    value: 2,
    next: null
};
/* CURRENT BINDING:
 *
 *    head ----> {value:2, next:null}
 */

-- Create a value and bind it to newObj
let newObj = {
    value: 1,
    next: head
};
/* CURRENT BINDING:
 *
 *  newObj ----> {value:1, next:
 *    head ---->     {value:2, next:null}
 *               }
 */

-- Bind the variable head to the value newObj is bound to.
head = newObj;
/* CURRENT BINDING:
 *
 * head,newObj
 *         ----> {value:1, next:
 *                   {value:2, next:null}
 *               }
 */

-- And see that it worked.
console.log(head)
```

Does that clarify your model of how programs represent data enough to understand why this code doesn't create a circular reference?

But if you're curious, it is possible to create circular references.

```
let foo = {value:1}:
foo['next'] = foo;
console.log(foo);
```

How did that work, isn't assignment just binding values to things?  Well, yes.  But if the thing that it is bound to is somewhere in a data structure, then that data structure had to get changed to allow it to be bound.

What happens after you create circular references varies by language. In JavaScript, at some point after it is bound to nothing, the garbage collector will clean it up.  In Python, it takes on a life of its own and you leak memory.  And so on.

Comment: Thanks. The way I understand is that values are created in memory and a variable is just a name with a “pointer” to that memory address. Meaning that during reassignment we are just changing the pointers, I have drawn this for myself on a sheet of paper with some arrows (based on your comment) and it is clear now. Also, I have been reading about pass by reference and pass by value and Javascript is essentially passing a copy of a reference as a value, which also helped me understand this better.

Comment: @89Tr34Ve That is exactly right.  And, in fact, the variables are themselves assigned to objects representing lexical scopes.  And when the scope itself goes out of scope, it can be kept in existence if it is referred to by something.  And now we're all the way to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures.

Comment: Historical note. Closures were invented in Pascal, but because it didn't have true garbage collection, you couldn't return them from functions. This severely limited them. They first achieved their modern utility in the Lisp dialect named Scheme. The inventor of JavaScript originally wanted to embed Scheme in the browser, but he was made to give it a syntax. And THAT is why JavaScript has closures!